# Add SQL command to report

Tags: crystal-reports

I want to make a Crystal Report based on a SQL statement. I've read to do that, you add a command to the report, and to do that you have to connect to a database.

[image]

When I click the browse button I get the following screen:
[image: Connecting to a database 2]

Based on my research, it seems you connect to a database. As seen above, all of the file types are .xml files and all that shows up is Dataset. After I click on that, and right click on the dataset name node, the Add Command to Report is greyed out:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Normally you'd be able to add a custom SQL command by right clicking *Add Command* and selecting *Add Command to Report* However ADO.NET requires some unique steps in order to add the custom SQL. Instead you'll want to navigate here:

*Create New Connection* → *OLE DB (ADO)* → *Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server*

[image]

[image]

You'll of course supply the server information and pick the database.

Comment: When I right click on Make New Connection after pointing to a dataset, Add Command to Report is still greyed out.

Comment: @Ralph Ah, I see what you mean! Turns out ADO.NET is a special case, I'll update my answer to include the new steps.

Comment: I'm using SQLServer Compact Edition if that makes a difference.

Comment: @Ralph I would think my latest answer should still apply. Did you have any more success with the OLE DB?

Comment: I tried Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server (I don't know what to put for the properties), and got the following error:

Logon failed. Details:  ADO Error code: 0x80040e4d. Source: Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server. Description: Invalid Authorization specification. SQL State: 28000

Comment: @Ralph Invalid authorization means you need to supply the correct login credentials for your table. The SQL Server is sending you the error, not Crystal.

Comment: I don't have any log in credentials, it's just a SQLServerCE DB with no user name or  password.

Comment: The problem was CR does not work with a SQLServer Compact Edition database. Access was in the list of databases to connect to, so I made a little Access database. I easily connected to it, and Add Command to Report was enabled, and I could base the report off of a SQL statement.

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out! You might want to submit your own answer explaining that, just in case it helps future viewers.

Answer (score 0):

After adding the connection: 
1) Click the plus sign next to your connection. 
2) Double-click the "Add Command" node. 
[image]

3) Type in your SQL query, click ok.
[image]

Source: Crystal Reports 2016 Online Help chm file.

HTH,

aEon'